# How did MyEtherApi manage to disallow some methods (Parity)

Tags: parity, nodes, rpc

I want to launch a public node with RPC enabled, open to others and for me. However, I want to disable the RPC methods that are unsafe to expose to the outside.

Looking at MyEtherApi, they have succesfully disabled some methods like "eth_accounts".
https://www.myetherapi.com/ same for https://infura.docs.apiary.io/ (Infura.io)

At this moment I am using Parity, switching over to Geth won't be a problem for me. I just want to get a node up and running safely.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, have been searching all day long. At last I tried posting the question on stackexchange and just 20 minutes later I seem to find the answer to my own question.

https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/Public-Node

running parity with `--public-node` seems to do the trick.

Comment: Note that this is not how these services actually achieve this goal. Infura use both Geth and Parity nodes (since Geth is better at some things, and Parity at others) and use custom middleware to route requests. I expect myetherapi is similar, but I haven't seen much about their architecture.